# Resources Bitmap file - does not contain a definition for Properties

Tags: c#, bitmap, resources

I have the following code skeleton for a Grasshopper component I am making. Grasshopper 3D is a plugin for Rhino 3D, a piece of architecture software. It's a graphical programming language. Anyways, below is a sample Abstract Class, in which I am adding a Bitmap icon to the component.

```
namespace HM_SettingsForm 
{
    public class HM_Settings : GH_Component
    {
        // Misc code

        protected override Bitmap Icon
        {
            get
            {
                return HM_SettingsForm.Properties.Resources.heatmap;
            }
        }
        // Misc code
    }
}
```

With that said, I am getting the following error.

[image]

Here is my Resources folder:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow I am silly. I overlooked that I used `HM_SettingsForm` twice.

Simply doing: `return Properties.Resources.heatmap;` worked.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I was getting the same Error. What I was doing was I had been adding the image to Resources folder. It was adding it, right. but not the definition. So then I double clicked to the Resources.resx in Properties window. (not the resources folder) then I dragged and droped the image into the Resources.resx window. So That image is copied to resources folder and its definition as well .
Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem, resolved it by referencing the Image (in my case a ToolStripMenuImage) from this:

```
this.tsm.Image = global::ASIM_Formatieren.Properties.Resources.icon_help;
```

to this

```
this.tsm.Image = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("icon_help");
```